# [type=search_context_missing_exception, reason=No search context found for id [5123123]]

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to use scrollApi, with its simplest approach:

```
public Stream<MyData> getAllRecords {
 Query searchQuery =
                new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                        .withPageable(PageRequest.of(0, 1000))
                        .withSourceFilter(MY_FILTER)
                        .build();
        searchQuery.setScrollTime(Duration.ofMillis(scrollTimeInMilis));
        IndexCoordinates index = IndexCoordinates.of("myIndex");
        elasticsearchOperations.searchForStream(searchQuery, MyData.class, index).stream().map(SearchHit::getContent);
}
```

And I am getting:

> org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.RestStatusException:
> Elasticsearch exception [type=search_phase_execution_exception,
> reason=all shards failed]; nested exception is
> ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception
> [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed]];
> nested: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception
> [type=search_context_missing_exception, reason=No search context found
> for id [427822]]];

I seems that `searchQuery.setScrollTime(Duration.ofMillis(scrollTimeInMilis))` does not help with it. I have 200k records in elasticsearch because I set `scrollTimeInMilis` to high values. I am using spring-data-elasticsearch 4.4.6.

I am also attaching the AbstractElasticsearchTemplate sources that seems to take scrollTime parameter into consideration and this looks similar as documentation approach https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.scroll:

```
public <T> SearchHitsIterator<T> searchForStream(Query query, Class<T> clazz, IndexCoordinates index) {
        Duration scrollTime = query.getScrollTime() != null ? query.getScrollTime() : Duration.ofMinutes(1L);
        long scrollTimeInMillis = scrollTime.toMillis();
        int maxCount = query.isLimiting() ? query.getMaxResults() : 0;
        return StreamQueries.streamResults(maxCount, this.searchScrollStart(scrollTimeInMillis, query, clazz, index), (scrollId) -> {
            return this.searchScrollContinue(scrollId, scrollTimeInMillis, clazz, index);
        }, this::searchScrollClear);
    }
```

Comment: The official SDE documentation shows an example of how to run a scrolled search: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.scroll

Comment: Yes but this seems to be the same that is done by spring data elasticsearch behind the scenes- i included spring sources in my post I am able to debug start and continue scrolling methods in Spring. Why it does not work, isn't it some library bug between spring and elastic rest client ?

Comment: That error could come from searchScrollStart call or from the searchScrollContinue, hard to say without a reproducible code example.

Comment: Rest of the code is out of my control - it is spring-data-es library. I will try with the complex approach from above link from Val.

Comment: Strange, but the searchForStream with scrollTimeInMilis did not work but the complex solution from Val link is working. Thanks.